# C question on casting

Tags: c++, c, sockets, casting

Can anybody explain me this statement!

```
pin.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)(hp->h_addr))->s_addr;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Takes `hp->h_addr`, and casts it to `struct in_addr*`. The cast may have different reasons. Perhaps `hp->h_addr` is `void*` and the cast is needed to tell the compiler what type it should use for finding `s_addr`. It may also be another struct that has an `in_addr` as its first member

```
struct in_addr {
  struct saddr_t s_addr;
};

struct socket {
  struct in_addr addr;
};

struct server {
  struct socket *h_addr;
};

server *hp;
```

Then, casting `socket*` to `in_addr*` would be valid because on its address there is a `in_addr` at the beginning. After the cast, the member `s_addr` is accessed. These types are common in network programming under POSIX, and don't look like in my above example, but the above could have been the situation at hand.

Answer (score 7):

It's casting the struct member h_addr as a struct in_addr* then referencing the s_addr member of the newly casted in_addr

Answer (score 4):

hp->a_addr is casted to a pointer to struct of type in_addr, in_addr has fields specified such as s_addr etc.

Unix sockets can handle different types of network addressing, internet addressing is just one of them, therefore one must cast the socket address descriptor to the correct one when accessing various fields.

For example sockaddr_in6 handles IPv6 addresses which is different from sockaddr_in.

Answer (score 1):

This treats `hp->h_addr` as though it points to a `struct in_addr`, and then tries to access the `s_addr` member of that `struct in_addr`

Answer (score 1):

hp is a **struct hostent** type pointer which is most likely to be returned by a "**gethostbyname()**" call. It has a member named h_addr which is actually an alias for the h_addr_list[0] (this holds the first IP address retrieved for your name query). In this case; you are passing this IP address to your **struct sockaddr_in** type variable "pin". It has a member named sin_addr with type **struct in_addr**.

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long int s_addr;
}

To complete the assignment, you should typecast h_addr to struct in_addr ptr (normally it is char*), then access to its s_addr member.

I hope this explains what is going on with you line.

Answer (score 0):

set the s_addr field of sin_addr field of structure containing variable pin 
with value placed in field s_addr which is located at address which pointed by h_addr field of structure contained in variable hp

in other words take addres from value of h_addr of hp and assume it points to (in_addr) and copy field s_addr to approriate field of pin.sin_addr

Answer (score 0):

From the inside ot:

- **`hp->h_haddr`** gets the `h_addr` member of the structure pointed to by `hp`.
- **`(struct in_addr *)`** casts this `h_addr` value to a pointer to an `in_addr` structure.
- **`->s_addr`** gets the `s_addr` member of the `in_addr` structure that it pointed to.

Therefore, it gets the `s_addr` member of the structure pointed to by the `h_addr` member of the structure pointed to by `hp`.  (`hp` and `h_addr` are both pointers)

It then assigns this value to `pin.sin_addr.s_addr`.

Answer (score 0):

(hp->h_addr) : get the h_addr field from pointer hp

((struct in_addr *)(hp->h_addr)) : cast the result from above statement to a pointer to in_addr struct

->s_addr : get the s_addr field from the resulting pointer of the above statement

= : assignment.